How to convert a Vec<String> to an array of string slices?
I have a Vec<String> and I would like to call a function that receives a &[&str] parameter, but I don't know how to convert one into the other.
For instance, how would call the mix_colours function in the following code?
fn main() {
    let colours: Vec<String> = vec!["blue".to_string(), "red".to_string(), "yellow".to_string()];
}

fn mix_colours(strings: &[&str]) {
    // ...
}


How did you attempt to solve it?

Relevant: Convert Vec into a slice of &str in Rust? (see this answer)

Although Vec can decay to &[] and String can decay to &str, we cannot perform these two decays in one step.
Since, in the end, we want a slice of &strs, this means that all these &strs must be stored contiguously.
The Strings are contiguous in the Vec but taking a &str from each of them just produces temporaries which are never stored together.
Then, we need to allocate a storage for them: a new Vec in this example.
If we don't want to allocate this new storage, we can change the parameter to &[impl AsRef<str>]: a slice of anything that can provide a reference to str.
This way, if we already have some contiguous &strs, we can pass them directly in a slice.
But, as in your example, if we have contiguous Strings, we can also pass them directly in a slice, because each of them will be asked .as_ref() inside the function.
(see mix_colours_bis())
fn main() {
    let colours: Vec<String> =
        vec!["blue".to_string(), "red".to_string(), "yellow".to_string()];

    let slice_of_colours: &[String] = colours.as_slice();
    // mix_colours(slice_of_colours); // impossible, &[String] is not &[&str]

    // we need a contiguous storage for many &str,
    // so that we can take a slice on all of them.
    let vec_of_str_colours: Vec<&str> =
        colours.iter().map(|c| c.as_str()).collect();

    let slice_of_str_colours: &[&str] = vec_of_str_colours.as_slice();
    mix_colours(slice_of_str_colours);

    mix_colours_bis(slice_of_colours);
    mix_colours_bis(slice_of_str_colours);
}

fn mix_colours(strings: &[&str]) {
    for s in strings.iter() {
        print!("{:?} ", s);
    }
    println!();
}

fn mix_colours_bis(strings: &[impl AsRef<str>]) {
    for s in strings.iter() {
        let r = s.as_ref(); // the only thing we know about s
        print!("{:?} ", r);
    }
    println!();
}
/*
"blue" "red" "yellow" 
"blue" "red" "yellow" 
"blue" "red" "yellow" 
*/


It can be wort mentioning, that instead of accepting &[T] one can take impl IntoIterator<Item = T>, if this function only iterates over slice elements.
